# Build swagger2 specs via spring-rest-docs

Tags: spring-restdocs

I like the TDD approach to documenting your restful api with spring-rest-docs. However, I love "API Playground" feature enabled by swagger specification. I wish there was a way to get best of both worlds.

Is there a way to build swagger2 specs from spring rest docs? may be via building custom request/response preprocessors.

Do you have any thoughts or recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not out-of-the-box support for this in Spring REST Docs at the moment. The [issue that you opened](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-restdocs/issues/213) will track the possibility of adding such functionality. In the meantime, your best bet would be to look at writing a custom `Snippet` implementation that generates (part of) a Swagger specification.

Typically, a Spring REST Docs snippet deals with documentating a single resource, whereas a Swagger specification describes an entire service. This means that the Swagger specification `Snippet` implementation will need to accumulate state somehow, before producing a complete specification at the end. There are lots of ways to do that (in memory, multiple files that are combined in a post-processing step, etc.). It's not clear to me that one approach is obviously the right one so some experimentation would be useful. If you do some experimentation, please comment on the issue that you opened with your findings.